# Is s-maxage supported by browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cache-control

I have a hard time finding out if `s-maxage` is supported by browsers, or by which versions of them.

`s-maxage` is primarily meant for shared caches, e.g. proxies or CDNs, but it seems to me that it also works in Chrome. For example, with a Next.js app that uses the [recommended cache-control header](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#caching-with-server-side-rendering-ssr) like this:

```
cache-control: public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59
```

I'm seeing this behavior in Chrome:

[image: Caching in Chrome]

However, I can't find a definitive resource like a MDN document or anything that would document it. Anyone knows?

Comment: What makes you say that it works on Chrome? Do you mean that if a page includes `maxage` and `s-maxage` directives Chrome will use the latter? That would be very surprising. `s-maxage` [only](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.9) applies to shared caches. That said, if no explicit expiration time is indicated I suppose the browser cache could use `s-maxage` for its [heuristic freshness](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.2) calculation.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks, that might be it. I've updated the question to include an example of what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expect browsers to respect `s-maxage`.

As defined in the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.9), `s-maxage` only applies to shared caches. A browser cache is generally considered to be a private cache.

I think what you're seeing is just the default caching that browsers do if you're not explicit about expiration. Since none of your headers provide an explicit [freshness lifetime](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.1), the cache is free to assign its own [heuristic freshness](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.2). It's normal to see a cache hit even if you don't provide any expiration directives.

It is possible that the browser takes `s-maxage` into account when computing its heuristic freshness, but I certainly wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, `s-maxage=10` really took effect – there was a revalidation after 10 seconds.