# Difference between public, max-age and s-maxage

Tags: http, caching, https, graphql, http-headers

**TLDR:**

> What is the difference between the `Public, max-age=<VALUE>` and
> `maxage=<VALUE>, s-maxage=<VALUE>` cache-control syntax?

**Question:**

For one of my projects, I am looking to reduce the server load via the `Cache-control` http-header. This project is hosted as a serverless function on Vercel and calls GitHub's GraphQL API on the backend to retrieve GitHub user information. Both the [Vercel API](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/edge-caching) and [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations) are rate limited, so I am looking for the best header to prevent these limits from being hit. To achieve this, I am currently using the following Cache-control header:

```
public, max-age=14400, stale-while-revalidate=86400
```

According to [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), this header should keep both the private browser cache and server cache fresh for 4 hours, while the stale cache can be reused for 1 day while it revalidates on the server. Furthermore, since I am not using an authentication header, I should be able even to remove the `Public` keyword.

The [Vercel cache documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/edge-caching), however, recommends the following header:

```
maxage=0, s-maxage=14400, stale-while-revalidate=86400
```

Based on the Vercel documentation and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992837/s-maxage-and-maxage-difference), I, therefore, think the following header is best suited for reducing both the Vercel and GitHub load:

```
maxage=14400, s-maxage=7200, stale-while-revalidate=86400
```

To my understanding, with this header, the cache will be fresh for 4 hours for individual users while the Vercel server refreshes the cache every 2 hours, and a stale cache can be reused for 1 day while it revalidates on the server.

As I am uncertain about the difference between the `Public, max-age=<VALUE>` and `maxage=<VALUE>, s-maxage=<VALUE>` syntax, I quickly wanted to double-check my understanding.

According to [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), these two syntaxes should result in the same behaviour if the `<VALUE>` is equal between `maxage` and `s-maxage` properties. However, the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/expiration.html#expiration-with-the-cache-control-header) states that the `s-maxage` flag prohibits a cache from using a stale response in stale-if-error scenarios. My question is, therefore: What is  the exact difference between these two syntaxes, and which one would you recommend for reducing the load on both the Vercel and GitHub api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vercel-recommended cache headers are well-suited to minimizing the number of API calls:

```
Cache-Control: maxage=0, s-maxage=N
```

The `s-maxage` is used to control caching by the Vercel Edge Network, allowing it to serve cached responses rather than call the serverless function. As far as I know it does not have rate limits of its own.

Of course, you probably have other caching goals besides just reducing API calls. So you might want to use `maxage` as well to allow browser caching to reduce latency for your users.

It's also a good idea to use `stale-while-revalidate`, but note that this is just a mechanism to reduce latency. The revalidation still happens, so it won't have an effect on the number of API calls.

As for `public`, it [means](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.5) "that any cache MAY store the response, even if the response would normally be non-cacheable or cacheable only within a private cache". If your response is already cacheable by a public cache then this directive won't have any effect.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your detailed response. You are right, Vercel currently doesn't have limits on the edge cache usage (see [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview)). Add `maxage` and `stale-while-revalidate` is therefore only needed to increase the user experience. May I ask you what is the browser cache behaviour when only `s-maxage` is specified. From the [documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-3) it looks like then both the browser and CDN use the `s-maxage` value.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with the `stale-if-error` limitation the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/expiration.html#expiration-with-the-cache-control-header) is talking about? This was discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/12934), but I can't find the exact logic in the documentation that states re-using of `stale-if-error` is prevented when `s-maxage` is enabled. I think in my cache, the `stale-while-revalidate` will take precedence over this behaviour, but I am curious about the default `stale-if-error` behaviour.

Comment: In short, what would be the behaviour of using the `maxage=14400, s-maxage=7200, stale-if-error=86400, stale-while-revalidate=86400` header? To my understanding, from reading the documentation you gave, since `s-maxage` is used, cache is stored both by the browser and the CDN with different time refresh rates. If the cache is no longer fresh on the browser, it will be requested from the CDN. If the cache is no longer fresh on the CDN it will return a stale response and update on the server. If an error is thrown on the CDN, a stale cache is served up to 1 day.

Comment: @rickstaa: 1) As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72385402/2395796) you shouldn't expect browsers to use `s-maxage`. 2) I don't know why the standard authors chose to make `s-maxage` imply `proxy-revalidate`, but that does indeed seem to be the case. The `stale-` directives were added later, though, and unfortunately the specifications do not indicate how they interact with the `-revalidate` directives. And since Vercel recommends using `s-maxage` and `stale-while-revalidate` together, they obviously are not preventing serving stale results when `s-maxage` is used. So I'm not sure.

Comment: @rickstaa: 3) Yes, that interpretation is correct, with the added fact that the browser will also use `stale-while-revalidate`, so the browser cache will return the stale result while it revalidates with the CDN.

Comment: Ah, good point about the `stale-while-revalidate` flag! Thanks again for your detailed response.

Comment: I just found in the [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#serverless-functions) that they don't support the `proxy-revalidate` flag.  Maybe because of the reasons explained above. So for Vercel deployments, people should not have problems with the `stale-if-error` flag.